# LTSpice BJT Model Help

Tags: bjt, ltspice, npn

I am new to LTSpice and I was trying to make some experiments with BJTs. In particular i was trying to model a npn with *VbeON* = 2V. From the the ltspice site i found that the built in potential of the Base-emitter junction is given by the parameter Vje, but it doesnt seem to work.

Here the schematic of what I am working on:
[image: Circuit Schematic]

But when i get to the simulation the operating point is still at more or less 0.6:

[image: Circuit Simulation]

Is there a way to do what I mentioned? Where I am making mistakes?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does exactly what the schematic implies it should do. This means that what you want to achieve is not going to be fulfilled by the circuit you chose AND, given that we only have the schematic, who knows what you are trying to do? Explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Andyaka he's trying to model a npn with VbeON = 2V.

Comment: @SredniVashtar - what does VbeON mean exactly to you?

Comment: @Andyaka what the user wants is clearly to have a transistor whose base emitter junction will show a threshold voltage of 2V. He thinks that that threshold is set by Vje, while in reality he needs to fiddle with the current Is

Comment: I'm not playing riddles so please don't say that. If you are sure about what he wants then leave an answer explaining what he should do.

Comment: Look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20090201102947/http://virtual.cvut.cz/dynlabmodules/ihtml/dynlabmodules/semicond/node48.html) for equations, you'll see that `Is` and `Nf` are the parameters you need to change, in particular `Nf` has the greatest influence. Use `.model mynpn npn Nf=2`, for example.

Comment: @Andyaka I wrote what he needs to do: by fiddling with Is he can modify the threshold voltage. I just did a simulation with .model myNPN npn (Is=84e-37) and you get that monster of a transistor the OP wants. It's all about solving the Shockley equation in reverse for the voltage you want when the current has a specified value. As concerned citizen points out, you can also modify Nf - and probably for that absurd value of threshold voltage is better. (I mean... 2V? that's a thrilington...)

Comment: It hasn't explicitly been mentioned yet, but for future reference the `Vje` parameter only serves to model the base-emitter junction capacitance.

Comment: Who edited my comment above and on what grounds? Also, why does it not show to have been edited?